# is the low-compressibility of seawater responsible for its bouyancy?

Tags: ocean, oceanography, water

I'm trying to wrap my head around water's density, low-compressibillity and bouyancy. Are all these 3 things related, if so, how?

I'm particularly interested if water's low compresibillity of responsible for the physiological appearance of marine organisims.

For example, small marine organisms are held by the density of water and as a result have amorphous spherical bodies suspended in a relatively viscous material. On the other hand, larger organisms need to move quickly through dense water and have stream-lined bodies. Consequently, you can deduce an organism's body size simply by looking at their body shape.

Or a briefer example, marine mammals' body weight are supported against gravity by the buoyancy of water, hence why oxygen-breathing marine mammals die when stranded as a result of crushing their organs through body weight.

Is the low-compressibillity of water responsible for these characteristics in marine organisims?